# Shared Printer on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, shared-printers

My company is upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 7.

One computer has a printer locally connected to it while other computers would connect remotely.

Post 10 Upgrade, only an admin, myself, is able to connect to it. Everyone who isn't an admin is met with 'Windows cannot connect to the printer.' and a 0x00000569 error.

I have double checked all the share settings, shared the spool/PRINTERS folder, made sure EVERYONE and NETWORK has full control but still nothing. Is there any other secret setting I missed?

Thank you

Comment: Are your computers in domain or workgroup environment? Also have a look how your Windows 10 computer treats its network connection: public, private or domain.

Comment: Set the "Point-and-Click" GPO to allow you users to load non-P&C drivers - which is disabled by default sind Windows 8.